# Does the Sparkfun ESP32 Thing is compatible with generic modules like DHT11 sensor?

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, temperature, arduino-esp32, sparkfun

First of all I am kind of a noob working with microcontrollers, by the way I am using **Arduino IDE 1.8.13**

I fallowed the [hookup guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp32-thing-hookup-guide) to set up [Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/software) to work with [Sparkfun ESP 32 Thing](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13907) board, and actually I was able to run the Arduino examples "Blink" and "Wifi" with no problem.

But my problem is when I tried to use the [DHT11](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/758/DHT11-Technical-Data-Sheet-Translated-Version-1143054.pdf) sensor, I did fallowed several tutorials like [this one](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-dht11-dht22-temperature-humidity-sensor-arduino-ide/) but for my bad fortune I did not succeed, instead I was getting NaN reading from the temperature and humidity sensor, at first I thought it might had something to do with the libraries version, which I installed and uninstalled several times, including the IDE, then using those same libraries I was able to do the exact same [example](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/pibots555/how-to-connect-dht11-sensor-with-arduino-uno-f4d239) on an [Arduino Uno](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-uno-rev3) microcontroller.

Then I realized I did not find any example, tutorial or document using the Sparkfun ESP32 Thing with the DHT11 sensor, since most of the examples that I found are for the generic ESP32.

Which makes me wonder, how can I know if those two components are compatible at all?

Does any one has faced something similar using ESP32 Thing with DHT11 or any another sensor?, if yes, how did you make it work or what did you do instead?

Comment: This looks like a question for [arduino.se]

Comment: Sensors (not only DHT11) are designed to be used by all kind of MCUs. You should focus on why you are getting an NaN than whether the sensor is compatible with a MCU.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that it might be library issue which might not work with the sparkfun board , the one I tried is "DHT Sensor Library by  Adafruit" which has a dependecy on "Adafruit Unified Sensor" but not 100% sure yet...

Comment: Adafruit's libraries usually work with ESP32 boards. You probably have it wired incorrectly or are using the library incorrectly. If you'd care to edit your question to share details of exactly how it's wired and a minimal viable example of code that demonstrates the problem, someone might be able to help.

Comment: I did like the tutorial I followed from the link above for esp32, I am using the DHT11 with 3 pins version, ok let me upstate with more details